# Index or Unique? What is better MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, unique

So i have a question.

Say you have a table requests, which represent a graph.  There are 3 columns in the request table, A, B, time.  A -> B At time.  So what each row represents is a directed connection from A (the requestor) to B (the requestee) at Time T (time is just for organizing data, not really for anything else).

So what is faster if say requests were 1,000,000 rows.
  Index(A, B)
  Index(A) and Index(B)
  Unique(A, B)?

Thanks guys!  And A, B are VARCHAR(32) (MD5's)

Sorry, i forgot a typical query.
I need to be able to see if User A (who logged on) has any requests!
I also will need to search to verify that a user has accepted a correct request, A Accepts B.

So the statements will look like.

Any new requests?

```
SELECT B, time
FROM requests
WHERE A='$id';
```

Does A have a request from B?

```
SELECT time
FROM requests
WHERE A='$A' and B='$B';
```

Comment: "Faster" depends on how you plan on searching against the data.  What would a typical query look like?

Comment: Oko, just updated the items.  Sorry i forgot to put the queries.  Ill probably be doing MANY more requests for NEW REQUESTS than for A have a request from B

Comment: I'd recommend put a normal index on both A and B, it will give you good performance and the flexibility you need. Do not use a unique constraint, MD5's can collide but the odds are tiny, you'll slow things down too much. Final point MD5 is no longer secure, `walk don't run to a more secure hash like SHA512.`

Comment: @Johan  What about if i salt my MD5's?

Comment: Salting is **always** needed, irrespective of the strength of the hash. MD5 can be made to collide, that's why it's not safe. SHA512 is safe from that.

Comment: Well that sucks that i did mD5, but luckily all hashing goes through a single method in my system so it should be to much to make everything become sha512 :) thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, use a composite index including A and B.  Make sure that A is first in the index.  That way when you run these two queries, the index would be used for both.

More on composite indexes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Also, uniqueness (A,B) shouldn't matter unless your requirement is that B can only request A **at most** once.

Comment: @AJ, I fail to see the use case for a compound index here, if I just want to lookup B, I'm screwed with the compound index. Please enlighten me?

Comment: @Johan - read the manual. "If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3). " The OP specified two queries: one that searches for values in A and one that searches for values in A,B. If there is a need to search on **just B**, the OP needs to specify that and I will revise my answer.

Comment: @AJ I know all that I just hate compound keys, because they kill your flexibility, better to start out with simple indexes and bring compound keys in after your db and frontend design have stabilized and you need that extra 5% in speed, or whatever tiny percentage compound keys give you. I see your point here though and technically you are correct and I'd upvote you if I didn't dislike those compound keys from hell so much.

Comment: Ha, your honesty is worth more to me than an upvote.  Bravo, sir.

Comment: YOu guys are both very giving good answers.  I think ill do Johan's suggestion with letting the inter workings stabilize then ill do compound indices.

Answer (score 39):

Index and unique are two completely different concepts.

**Indexes**
An index is a hidden extra column holding the same data sorted with a pointer to your real data. Using an index you can

1. Quickly find a particular item
2. Quickly find a range of items *(between x and y)*
3. Save time when using `order by` because the items are presorted
4. Save time when using `group by` because group by needs to match identical items

This is a normal index, it doesn't mind duplicate values, except for the primary key which is always unique.

**Unique (Index)**
If you want to avoid duplicate values you can put a `unique index` on it. This will do all of the above, but add an extra check **on every update and insert** to check whether that values is not already in the database. If you try to insert a duplicate row on a unique column, MySQL will give an error and refuse your insert.
*(you cannot make a row `unique` without using an index)*

Use of indexes slows inserts and updates down.
Use of unique indexes slows then even more down.

However indexes speed up `select` a lot, a whole lot.
`Unique` doesn't speed up anything it makes sure you don't accidentally insert a duplicate row.

**When to use indexes and when not**
Don't put an index on every field. As stated above it will slow you `insert`s and `update`s down.
Always put an index on join criteria. And seriously consider putting an index on column you use in `where` clauses a lot.
MySQL will refuse to use an index if 50% of your rows have the same value in a field, so forget about indexes on boolean *(Y/N)* fields, 99% of the time they will not work.
*(Indexes in low cardinality fields are not useful)*

**Always assign a primary key**
Always assign a primary key on your table though. Preferably of type `integer autoincrement`. If **you** don't assign a primary key, MySQL will assign a 'hidden' primary key for you *(of type integer autoincrement)*, but you cannot use the hidden PK to speed up quotes or identify your rows and there are a host of other slowness problems with hidden PK's which make them suck very badly.

Hope this helps.

**Links:**
How MySQL uses indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html
When to use indexes: http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases
More of that stuff: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm
Finally lurk here if you want to know more about MySQL: http://planet.mysql.com/

Comment: Great answer btw,  I was just reviewing one of these old questions.  This is the more informative answer! :)